# How to make Swagger generate model schema enum as string instead of int?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, .net-core-3.0

I have a Web API project build on .NET Core 3 and my Startup looks like this.

```
services.AddControllers(o => o.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddMvcOptions(o =>
                {
                    //Add mvc options here
                })
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
                {
                    o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                    o.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                    o.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'";
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
```

Swagger generates schema as:

```
status  MyEnumStatusinteger($int32)
Enum:
[ 1, 2, 3]
```

My C# enum looks like this:

```
public enum TimesheetWorkflowStatus
    {
      NotStarted = 1,
      InProgress = 2,
        Completed = 3
  }
```

Why is Swagger dcumenting this enum as int and not string? I tried using `DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings` but it has been rendered obsolete. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution from [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1349#issuecomment-572537295). I had to add `services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport()` alongwith `services.AddSwaggerGen()` to make it work.